# What to do when VeraCrypt "Repair Filesystem" literally takes forever and blocks you from working?

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, ntfs, filesystem-corruption, veracrypt

**Update** (I'm the poster who has lost access to the account): The command "WMIC diskdrive get Status,Model" claims that the "health" of the disk is "OK". But File Explorer just hangs forever if you try to browse/list files from the disk. The "repair" seems to be taking literally forever. Would hate to have to retire this disk after so little time. I expected to never throw them away, or at the soonest after 25 years.

My USB HDD (WD, 9 years old) is acting up. When mounting it in VeraCrypt, it just loads forever and hangs my whole system. So I right-click it in VeraCrypt and have selected both "Check Filesystem" and "Repair System" all day, but it just gets stuck in perpetual busywork of some kind, like this:

```
Attempting to repair the file system on the VeraCrypt volume mounted as H:...
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is BAKDISK 7.
Fixing critical master file table (MFT) files with MFT mirror.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
Deleting corrupt file record segment 0.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0x80, "")
from file record segment 0x1.
File record segment 4 is unreadable.
File record segment 5 is unreadable.
File record segment 6 is unreadable.
File record segment 7 is unreadable.
File record segment 8 is unreadable.
File record segment 9 is unreadable.
File record segment A is unreadable.
File record segment B is unreadable.
File record segment C is unreadable.
File record segment D is unreadable.
File record segment E is unreadable.
File record segment F is unreadable.
File record segment 10 is unreadable.

[tons of similar stuff redacted]

File record segment 1FA is unreadable.
File record segment 1FB is unreadable.
File record segment 1FC is unreadable.
File record segment 1FD is unreadable.
File record segment 1FE is unreadable.
File record segment 1FF is unreadable.
File record segment 200 is unreadable.
File record segment 201 is unreadable.
File record segment 202 is unreadable.
File record segment 203 is unreadable.
File record segment 204 is unreadable.
Progress: 517 of 716288 done; Stage:  0%; Total:  0%; ETA: 999:00:00 ...
```

At this pace, it's never going to finish. I've already spent all day like this. I have to abort it and turn off the computer soon. Even if I would keep it overnight, I know from experience and a gut feeling that it would still be saying "999" hours for ETA.

I've had numerous similar problems over the years, and I highly doubt that there is something physically wrong with the disk, because even when they act up like this, they go back to working.

What am I supposed to do in situations like this?

Comment: "What am I supposed to do in situations like this?" - Restore from a backup, your external drive, has suffered a catastrophic failure.

Comment: It *IS* the backup (or one of them). Not buying new stuff until absolutely necessary.

Comment: Your 9 year old drive has suffered a catastrophic failure.  There is no recovery from hundreds of file segments being unreadable.  Considering the data is encrypted standard data recovery tools would be useless unless the drive was mounted and readable by those tools (which you have indicated is impossible due to the fact it would take 999 hours).

Comment: @Ramhound It cannot possibly take this long to scan the damn drive. Something is wrong.

Comment: Yes, something is wrong, it's a catastrophic failure. I don't know how to make it more clear and also make even more clear that there's NO recovery.

Comment: @Kyonte - Yes; The drive has failed. It attempts to read a sector, likely encounters an I/O error, and the result is an inaccurate estimate.  The fact it has recovered in the past is unrelated to this failure, in the past, you were lucky.

Comment: There's a page in the Help section about merging your accounts. Please use that to make your life easier.